# WebRTC stream webcam browser to C/C++ native application

Tags: c++, video-streaming, webrtc

I have some troubles with the WebRTC API (and most particularly RTCPeerConnection).

I have successfully managed to make a video call between two browsers : I know how to get the webcam stream with getUserMedia, I know how to contact a STUN server and react on 'onicecandidate' event and I know how to create the offer (and the answer in the other peer) and send the sdp.
I use WebSockets as a signalling channel.

What I need to do is process the video stream with C/C++ algorithms, so I am looking for a way to receive a RTCPeerConnection in C/C++ and receive a call **in C/C++**.

I have been trying to build and test Google's libjigle library (haven't succeeded yet, though (I'm on Archlinux)). But even when I succeed, I don't see how to re-use the code for my own case.

## What I have done so far :

- I understand how STUN servers work, ICE candidates and SDP sessions and how to create / process them **in javascript**
- I managed to make *peer-to-peer* calls between two browsers (and even between a PC and my Android and this worked perfectly)
- I managed to use libwebsockets to create a simple signalling server, in which I successfully receive the browser's ICE candidates and sdp messages.

## What I am looking for :

- A way to receive/parse/process **in C/C++** what the browser sends *i.e.* ICE candidates, sdp, offer
- A way to create the *answer* (the browser will always be the initiator) and receive/process the webcam stream.

## What I have tried :

- I have tried to have the webcam play in a  HTML5 element, and periodically (~ 33ms) draw the frame in a , call getImageData() and send the array of (R,G,B,alpha) with a pure WebSocket connection. But even for a 100x100 px, grayscale frame (hence 10kB), I can only achieve ~7fps with a ~600 kb/s upload stream. **This is why I want to use RTCPeerConnection which works on UDP**

## My constraints :

- I need to run the native app in C or C++ because I have image/video processing algorithms that are implemented in C++ (*I have seen a lot of Node.js-based servers but I can't have that : no way to call my algorithms*)
- I'd like to be able to run at roughly 30 fps so that this is relatively fluid for the user.
- I can't use Flash or Silverlight : I need to stay HTML5 / javascript for the client

## Conclusion :

- Where I fail short is everything that deals with ICE candidates, SDP sessions and contact STUN server in C/C++ because unlike javascript there are no events ('onicecandidates', 'onaddstream', etc).

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The Native API or using a breaker (similar to [RTC WebBreaker](http://webrtc2sip.org/#aRTCWebBreaker)) should work for you.

Comment: I am precisely trying to use the native API, but I have no clue how to begin.
I found [this native API](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis)  which seems to refer to libjingle.
I have been trying to build libjingle for four days now but I can only build some parts (make all fails, but make peerconnection_server succeeds for instance).

Anyway, can somebody explain to me how I can start using the library and the classes to build even a small working program ? I am totally lost here.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I have a similar issue (actually the reverse problem, streaming series of images in memory from Python/C++ application to a webpage).